# backbone.js - loading .js files when needed with require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I found interesting link on how to organize my files and load files using require.js http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/ , the only issue I have with that example is that they load everything in the beginning even asynchronously. I was wondering if it is possible load .js files only when they needed... For example if I click on Project List ( http://backbonetutorials.com/examples/modular-backbone/#/projects ), it checks on which url we are currently located, and load projects.js and list.js after that....
For small apps it would be ok, but for big apps with big classes it might take a while, before all classes will be loaded to the browser, for all routers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think creator of that example answered this question more accurately. Here is his answer: http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/#IDComment-CommentText210764496 , see the reply

Comment: For anyone still looking for an explanation check out how I loaded the routes with http://backbonetutorials.com/nodejs-restify-mongodb-mongoose/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would really need a big application in order to need that. The files of a normal application, minified and gzipped, are not a significant load. And then you can use caching to load them only once in each browser.

If you really want to, of course you can do partial loading, in the same way you do it for the application in the example (in the router, the `projects` route will first ensure the project-related js files are loaded, and only then do the fetching/view initialization etc)